# How to Create Parent Magento Store Which has Multiple Stores Underlying it With Different Domains

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

I am stuck how to create a Magento Parent Store Which has Multiple Stores Underlying it Configured on Different Domains with one Hosting plan.

For example I have a Parent Store

abc.com

Underlying Store

store1.com
store2.com
store3.com
store4.com

I know how to create stores and different Catalogs assigned to them and Different User Roles assigned to them Buh i need is how do i make them Routed from Different Domains How to make change in Code in Index.php i have Tried 2-3 Code snippets Buh they Didn't work for me.

I need is When User Hits Store1.com then my Store1 which is Underlying my parent Store Will be Called.

Comment: Are you using shared or dedicated hosting?

Answer (score 2):

create a folder structure :

```
magento/ < -- magento installation
magento/htdocs < -- copy index.php and symlink skin, media, errors, js .htaccess
magento/htdocs/store1 < -- copy index.php and symlink skin, media, errors, js, .htaccess
magento/htdocs/store2 < -- copy index.php and symlink skin, media, errors, js, .htaccess
```

in idex.php change include path for $compilerConfig and $mageFilename to pint to right filepath (../ or ../../) and on each index.php start store by storecode

```
Mage::run('storecode', 'store');
```

Point your subdomains to your new homedirectories. Benefits you get:

- core code is not in public folder
- each store has its own public folder
- all sites use the same codebase

Comment: I really like this solution, especially as it keeps the codebase out of the doc root.

Comment: actually there are more benefits if you use automated deployments in such cases and you can test all sites from single parent path on test servers